# Can PayPal NVP refunds show refunded line items in refund emails?

Tags: php, email, paypal, paypal-nvp

I'm performing refunds using `PayPal NVP's RefundTransaction` call, and I'd like the refund confirmation emails that `PayPal` sends out to show the refunded line items.

Currently, the refund confirmation emails only show the original order line items, as in the following shortened email:

---

### test facilitator's Test Store has just sent you a refund

5 Apr 2016 20:49:50 PDT | Transaction ID:

Dear test buyer,

test facilitator's Test Store has just sent you a partial refund of $0.50 AUD for your purchase. 
...

### Original transaction details

### Payment details

```
Description:  Item #1 description,
Unit price: $0.50 AUD
Quantity: 2
Amount: 

Description:  Item #2 description,
Unit price: $2.50 AUD
Quantity: 3
Amount: 

Shipping and handling: $9.90 AUD
Insurance: N/A

Total: $18.40 AUD

Refund  PayPal balance: $0.50 AUD
```

Sincerely,
PayPal

---

However, the docs for RefundTransaction seem to indicate that I can pass additional parameters like `L_INVOICEITEMNAMEn and L_PRICEn`, but they appear not to have any effect.

Can `PayPal NVP` refunds show refunded line items in refund emails, and if so, how can it be done?